# How can I get information about a file or folder on a Linux system?

Tags: linux, files

I need to get detailed information of certain file or folder, such as chmod, changed date, which user.

How can I do this?

Comment: You might give ls -al or stat <filename> a try

Comment: Either you have to audit it or stat it when you want.

Comment: I think stat reports more info about file for my needs.

Comment: I think some malicious script changed my php file chmod settings so i need to know details of that to increase security

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use inotifywait

Try like this:

```
inotifywait -e attrib -m the_folder_to_watch
```

Where `-e` is the event to monitor, `-m` is monitor continuously.

See the blogpost here: http://en.positon.org/post/A-solution-to-the-umask-problem%3A-inotify-to-force-permissions

And the man for inotifywait: http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this (that I know of, I could be corrected and learn something as well) unless you've installed a package to handle this. Meaning, if you didn't plan ahead and monitor a file, there is no way to get this information. All you'll be able to get from the file is the basic information that the `stat <filename>` cmd shows you, which wont show you what user altered a file.

That being said, in the future there are packages like audit that help you handle this and after you set a file to be audited, a simple `ausearch -f <filename>` would allow you to see this type of information.
You could also use something like aide -- which I personally like.